# Extracting the machine account domain password from the registry

Tags: samba, active-directory

If I understand correctly, to join a Windows domain, a machine needs to have an account on Active Directory, and have the password to authenticate. Such a password is renewed automatically every 30 days.

Now, I have a Linux machine on the corporate network, with the IT dept's blessing, and Samba can join a domain and would allow me to do so, but they don't want to add it. I want to use the account I have on a Windows machine I'm going to reformat anyway. I couldn't find a way to decode the key stored in the registry.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to dump the hashes from a Windows system and import them into Samba. The process is explained here http://ppp.samba.org/samba/ftp/pwdump/README. However do consider the IT department might not be happy with you doing such things and there is no guarante that it will work for what your trying to do.

Comment: I'll look into this, but I'm not sure this is going to work on XP. 
As for the IT dept, weeell, how shall I say, they are certified Mediocre Or Relatively Ordinary Network Specialists™. They couldn't even find a worm-infected laptop on the network, they had to go door to door to run manual checks instead of looking up the offending MAC on the switches.

Comment: If your sure its a route you wish to pursue you might want to checkout Cain & Abel its a very good program for retriving hashes ammongst other things. But be warned it could be considered a bit dodgy, I have used it previously to get system hashes.

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully the IT group is as respectful about you as you are about them (sarcasm intended). What does it benefit you to disparage and insult them? Does it make you a better developer? Does it make your boss respect you more? Does it make you a better person? No? Then why do it? There's no glory and certainly no honor in bashing someone else's abilities.

Comment: Oh they hate me alright. Thing is, everybody in the company hates them. They have to endure their incompetence, lose countless hours to their inanity. Imagine having a 10Mbps internet connection for 500 users and *all* the apps are hosted remotely and have to go through that bottleneck. If they knew how set up a simple MRTG they would see the problem, but that's beyond them.

But beyond venting off my frustration, I posted those details so as to preempt comments such as that of Chopper3 ... to little effect obviously.

Comment: Well it seems emotions are running high on this one. I feel for you. I usually just try to stifle my frustration as I'm sure someone in the world is grumbling about what a schmuck I am.

Comment: Do unto others ... well that might just be the problem: I've never had one with criticism. I'd rather have someone tell me how I could things better. The people I'm talking about here cannot even take simple advice or even a bug report. The other day I had trouble downloading a Linux ISO because there (still) is a problem with the firewall (AFAICT); I filed a ticket with logs and all the technical details, they responded with a passive-aggressive email saying what an insensitive clod I was for hogging the bandwidth and how I should download at home. No kidding.

Answer (score 1):

Question: Why would you need to join a Windows domain?

At work, I use Linux only. The entire infrastructure is Windows. I mount Windows shares without problems:

```
mount -t smbfs "//fileserver/sharename" /mnt/mntpoint/ \
-o credentials=filename,uid=...,gid=...,fmask=0755,dmask=0755
```

The credentials file looks like:

```
username=DOMAIN/username
password=mywindowspassword
```

I have a simple script I run after logging in that mounts all the shares I need (I run it manually, since I am not always on the company network). Whenever I need to change the domain password, I just edit the credentials file. I usually find out that my password is expired when the shares stop working. I then borrow a colleague's Windows computer and log in using that. Windows prompts me to change the password.

I am not sure if what you ask makes sense for a Linux computer. What would joining a Windows domain mean for a Linux box?

**Edit:**

I get it. Your Linux box is a SMB file server? And you want to make it available for the Windows users?

Comment: Not quite, I can't seem to be able to print without joining the domain; I used to be able to through CUPS by setting my password in the URL to the printer, but they changed something and it doesn't work anymore.

Comment: I voted you up because it's informative, even though it didn't answer the question; I'm doing that kind of thing already for file servers (actually automagically through Gnome), but that's not joining the domain.

Comment: Have you tried printing using smbclient. Have not tried it myself, but found some info on the net. Se for instance http://www.unix.com/unix-dummies-questions-answers/94746-smbclient-print-while-preserving-windows-printer-settings.html

Comment: Yeah that's what I was doing, only through CUPS. I get rejected every time now.